# Documenting commands with starred versions

Tags: dtx

Have been looking at the latex `.dtx` files on how starred commands are described.

Although I have seen

```
\item[|*|] If present the theorem is unnumbered, otherwise it is
./latex3/xpackages/xtheorem/xtheorem.dtx-%   numbered.
```

there is also

```
\newcommand|*|\marg{\cs{FOO}}\oarg{i}\marg{TEXT}
```

I want to ask about the proper way to document the following command.

```
\NewDocumentCommand {\dkmLadr} { s m }
```

From what I have seen, the way is not to use the square brackets.

Thusly using

```
 \dkmLadr|*|\marg{KVI}
```

Other possibilities include

```
 \dkmLadr[|*|]\marg{KVI}

 \dkmLadr\meta{*}\marg{KVI}

 \dkmLadr\oarg{*}\marg{KVI}
```

Comment: The star is appended to the command's name without square brackets. When I document a command with a starred variant I usually first document the unstarred variant and then say something like, "The starred variant is similar but..." The behavior is usually, only slightly different from the unstarred variant (there is some variation of course).

Comment: There are no square brackets in `\item[|*|]`, the `[]` makes it an optional argument to `\item`. I tend to use `\meta{*}` personally to document optional stars.

Comment: I can then use the approach used in `./latex2e/base/ltdefns.dtx:` for `\newcommand`.